# Ado.net Update statement times out when a large parameter is added

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-server-2014

I am using this piece of code to execute an update command using ADO .Net

```
private void UpdateTableUsingCommand(int id, string updatedText)
{
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var sqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                sqlCommand.CommandText = $"UPDATE [{TableName}] SET [{TextColumnName}]=@1 WHERE [{IdColumnName}]=@2";

                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = ConvertToUTF8(updatedText);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", id);

                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
}
```

But whenever the `updatedText` length exceeds 8k characters, the `ExecuteNonQuery` method throws timeout exception.

Note: when I try to update the same cell using SQL Server Management Studio, it is updated without timing out.

Comment: In c# a SQL Command default timeout is 30 seconds.  You have to make it larger : sqlCommand.Timeout = 500;

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for replying, but I 've tried the same process using Entity framework and SQL Server management studio and both executed properly in less than 30 seconds, I need this statement to be executed within the same timeframe using ADO .Net, too.

Comment: The default driver for SQL,Client is much slower than Entity and SQL Server.  See following for a list of drivers : https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Also see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/sql-connection-libraries?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your advice, Unfortunately, Setting the timeout to 500 did not resolve the issue, Timeout exception is thrown after 500 seconds.

Comment: I 've also tried replacing System.Data.SqlClient with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, didn't help, either

Comment: What does `ConvertToUTF8` do and why do you think you need it. And why are you using dynamic SQL? More the point: how do you know the column is `nvarchar(max)` if you don't know the table or column name?

Comment: @jdwend Can you back that statement up, I'm not aware there is any difference as EF uses the standard driver under the hood

Comment: @Charlieface I am using dynamic SQL because the targeted names change per database, but the targeted columns are nvarchar(MAX) in all the targeted databases, the ConvertToUTF8 is used to convert the processed string to UTF-8 before storing it, The whole idea of that project is that I need to migrate that column from an old database to a new one, but the old databases are using different scheme.

Comment: @Charlieface I cannot use entity framework because I don't have a unified table model to map on.

Comment: Firstly `nvarchar(max)` is UTF-16, secondly (even for `varchar` with a UTF-8 collation) ADO.Net always passes both `nvarchar` and `varchar` as string, not as bytes. And why don't you just use a migration tool

Comment: @Charlieface in order to migrate the data, I have to do some operations on it before saving it to the new database, So I have to select the data, process it and save it in the new database.

Comment: OK but why are you "converting to UTF-8"? Just pass the string

Comment: Tried passing the string without converting it and that doesn't resolve the issue, the ExecuteNonQuery method throws timeout exception.

Comment: Very strange. Please [edit] and add the full generated SQL, plus the table in question with its indexes. What size is the string?

Comment: I don't have access to the database itself to get the full table scheme, but as you can see in the question, the resulted SQL statement body is in the code.

As for the string size, it's size is ranging from 10k to 23k characters

Comment: @Charlieface : Look at my 2nd link above.  the are plenty of links on web that look for faster methods instead of the SQL Client.  I've seen cases in work where SSMS take 30 seconds to do the same that take over 30 minutes using SQL Client with exactly the same command text.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not prepared to believe that, it sounds like you run into problems with parameter sniffing, see [Erland Sommarksog: Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) who debunks the whole issue

Comment: @Charlieface : I have very large databases and using Express.

Comment: @jdweng Please back your statement up. The only links you have provided are how to switch between the ADO.NET driver and the newer Microsoft.SqlClient, which I admit may be faster although nowhere does it say so, but as I said, in EF only the standard client is supported https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/823

Comment: @Charlieface : I do not think your correct.  As long as a driver is installed on machine and the connection string uses the driver any driver can be used.  You are referencing a posting where the response could be wrong.  Show me in a MSDN  app note then I will believe you.

Comment: I was fiddling around the problem again, it turns out that increasing the network packet in the connection string solved the issue, Until it crashed again with timeout exception, this time it crashed on a 7.7 k characters long update statement.